# How do I get a reference to one of my HTML meta tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a meta tag like so in my ASP.NET MVC View:

```
<meta name = "currentRequestAbsoluteUri" 
 content="@Url.Content(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)" />
```

Using JavaScript or jQuery, how do I read the value of this meta tag?

I can do it using JavaScript but it is long-winding:

```
var element = 
document.getElementByName('currentRequestAbsoluteUri');

// And then how do I get its content property
// like this?
// var content = element["content"]
```

Wait, I am not even sure if HTML DOM API has that function to get something by its name.

I can also use jQuery but jQuery uses sizzle, the CSS selector engine and I don't know how to get an element like meta because it has neither an id nor a CSS class.

Comment: There’s no `getElementByName`, only `getElementsByName`. It’s plural, because multiple elements can have the same name. You’d need to select _one_ element, however: `document.getElementsByName('currentRequestAbsoluteUri')[0].content`.

Comment: For what it's worth, `meta` tags aren't supposed to be just a generic way to add random bits of data to your page. I'm not sure what your actual goal is here, but more likely than not it would be simpler to just set a namespaced JS variable with this value and be done with it: `MyNamespace.CurrentRequestAbsoluteUri = '@Url.Content(...)';`

Comment: And now that I think about, why not just use `location.href`? If all you're getting is the current page URL, that's available directly in JS.

Comment: @ChrisPratt: Thank you. Never thought about that. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use css attribute selectors. Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

You can use the css attribute selectors in JS using `querySelector`. Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

```
var meta  = document.querySelector("meta[name='currentRequestAbsoluteUri']");
var value = meta.content;
```

Comment: Thank you. And then how do I get its content attribute's value?

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 Add `.content`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`document.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName). It returns an array-like HTMLCollection that contains all meta tags in the DOM. You can then iterate through it to get your reference to meta tags. Each item

```
var metaTags = document.getElementsByTagName('meta');
var metaTagsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(metaTags);

metaTagsArray.forEach(function(metaTag){
  var metaTagName = metaTag.name;
  var metaTagContent = metaTag.content;
});
```

You can optionally turn it into an array using `slice` to have access to native array methods, like `forEach`.

Comment: You should probably make the `forEach` example a bit clearer. Right now, it just overwrites variables in each loop iteration and makes the variables inaccessible beyond the function scope…